# Запуск и остановка метода с клавиатуры в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на одну клавишу клавишу начиналось выполнение метода, например, секундомер, и после нажатия на вторую клавишу, секундомер должен остановится?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `EventHandler` для такой работы, в Java 7 и выше есть возможность прикрепить к клавишам клавиатуры, так называемые, действия (ивенты). Закрепите за сценой или нужным вам стейджем следующую функцию: `scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {}`

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key){
    if(key.getCode().getPressed().equals("КНОПКА ЗАПУСКА")){
        // пуск подпрограммы
    } else if (key.getCode().getPressed().equals("КНОПКА СТОПА")){
        // стоп подпрограммы
    } else {
        ;
    }
}
```